# java.util.InputMismatchException when using Scanner and .nextInt()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am just trying to make a simple program to have some fun but i got this code here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);
        char reply;
        reply = (char) keyboard.nextInt();
        if (reply == 'y' || reply == 'Y') {
            out.println(":-)");
        } else {
            out.println(":-(");
        }
        keyboard.close();

    }

}
```

And i got this output:

```
y
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at test5.main(test5.java:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `y` and `Y` characters can't be converted to `int`s, hence the exception. Unfortunately, `Scanner` doesn't have a `nextChar()` method, but you could just use Strings instead:

```
String reply = keyboard.next();
if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    out.println(":-)");
} else {
    out.println(":-(");
}
```